# SUM in SQL Server with multiple lines on one side of JOIN and one side on the other as a comparison

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a situation I am trying to find out.  I am trying to compare two sets of data on the qty at a size level.  It seems simple enough but the issue is in some cases the qty can be split out on two lines on one side of the equation thus I would have two lines of 250 comparing to one line of 500.  They are equal in total but the query I am writing doesn't seem to work.  I have posted the query below with some output.  In the first result material D68154 size L has two lines on the "M" side of the query totaling 500 and one line on the "A" side of the query totaling 500.  In my ideal case this result wouldn't come back as I wan't to compare only where the sums are actually different.  Any ideas? Thanks.

Query:

```
SELECT
    M.STOCK_NUMBER AS [PO_NUMBER],
    M.MATERIAL, 
    M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
    M.SIZE_LITERAL,
    A.GRID_VALUE,
    SUM(M.QUANTITY) AS [PO_QTY],
    SUM(A.QUANTITY) AS [SO_QTY],
    M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    M.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    M.PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE AS [ETA],
    M.PLANT_CODE

FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION M
JOIN VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW A   
    ON M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER AND
       M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER AND
       M.STOCK_NUMBER = A.SAP_PO_NUMBER AND
       M.SIZE_LITERAL = A.GRID_VALUE AND

       M.MATERIAL = A.MATERIAL_NUMBER
WHERE
    M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'KE' AND
    M.STOCK_TYPE NOT IN ('A','C') AND
    M.STOCK_NUMBER IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
    M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.MATERIAL, 
    M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
    M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    M.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    M.PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE,
    M.PLANT_CODE, 
    A.GRID_VALUE
HAVING

    SUM(M.QUANTITY) <> SUM(A.QUANTITY)

ORDER BY
    M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.SIZE_LITERAL;
```

Results:

```
PO_NUMBER    MATERIAL           MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION                     SIZE_LITERAL GRID_VALUE PO_QTY                                  SO_QTY                                  SALES_ORDER_NUMBER SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER                 CUSTOMER_NAME                       ETA                     PLANT_CODE
------------ ------------------ ---------------------------------------- ------------ ---------- --------------------------------------- --------------------------------------- ------------------ --------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- ----------------------- ----------
0283127530   D68154             GRAPHIC BRA         BLACK/WHITE          L            L          250                                     500                                     6194098835         10                                      ROSS STORES INC                     2018-03-31 00:00:00.000 6010
0283127530   D68154             GRAPHIC BRA         BLACK/WHITE          L            L          250                                     500                                     6194098835         10                                      ROSS STORES INC                     2018-04-28 00:00:00.000 6010
0283127530   D68154             GRAPHIC BRA         BLACK/WHITE          M            M          250                                     500                                     6194098835         10                                      ROSS STORES INC                     2018-03-31 00:00:00.000 6010
0283127530   D68154             GRAPHIC BRA         BLACK/WHITE          M            M          250                                     500                                     6194098835         10                                      ROSS STORES INC                     2018-04-28 00:00:00.000 6010
0283127560   D68153             BOLT TANK           DGSOGR               L            L          250                                     500                                     6194098839         10                                      ROSS STORES INC                     2018-03-31 00:00:00.000 6010
0283127560   D68153             BOLT TANK           DGSOGR               L            L          250                                     500                                     6194098839         10                                      ROSS STORES INC                     2018-04-28 00:00:00.000 6010
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data,that will be helpful.

Comment: an example would be the results above - in this instance material D68154 with a size of 'L' has two entries in the MRP "M" table - each with different Planned delivery dates for 250 each (total of 500) - this splits it into two lines which is fine.  The correlating value in the ARUN "A" table only has one entry with a total of 500.  For my purposes these actually match and shouldn't get returned in the comparison I am just not sure how to get there with different numbers of lines on each side of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a subquery for `VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW`.
As variant

```
SELECT
    ...    
FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION M
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,
      SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,
      SAP_PO_NUMBER,
      GRID_VALUE,
      MATERIAL_NUMBER,
      SUM(QUANTITY) QUANTITY
    FROM VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW
    GROUP BY SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,SAP_PO_NUMBER,GRID_VALUE,
      MATERIAL_NUMBER
  ) A   
    ON M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER AND
       M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER AND
       M.STOCK_NUMBER = A.SAP_PO_NUMBER AND
       M.SIZE_LITERAL = A.GRID_VALUE AND
       M.MATERIAL = A.MATERIAL_NUMBER
WHERE
    M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'KE' AND
    M.STOCK_TYPE NOT IN ('A','C') AND
    M.STOCK_NUMBER IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY
    M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.MATERIAL, 
    M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
    M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    M.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    M.PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE,
    M.PLANT_CODE, 
    A.GRID_VALUE
HAVING
    SUM(M.QUANTITY) <> SUM(A.QUANTITY)
ORDER BY
    M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.SIZE_LITERAL;
```

And as variant you can use `DISTINCT` in your query but I don't think it's a good way.

Try to check one more variant

```
SELECT
    M.STOCK_NUMBER AS [PO_NUMBER],
    M.MATERIAL, 
    M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
    M.SIZE_LITERAL,
    A.GRID_VALUE,
    SUM(M.QUANTITY) [PO_QTY],
    SUM(A.QUANTITY) AS [SO_QTY],
    M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    M.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    M.PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE AS [ETA],
    M.PLANT_CODE,
    M.STOCK_TYPE
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      STOCK_NUMBER,MATERIAL,MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION,SIZE_LITERAL,SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,CUSTOMER_NAME,PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE,PLANT_CODE,STOCK_TYPE,
      QUANTITY,
      SUM(QUANTITY) OVER(PARTITION BY STOCK_NUMBER,MATERIAL,SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,SIZE_LITERAL) SUM_QUANTITY
    FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION
    WHERE REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'KE' AND
        STOCK_TYPE NOT IN ('A','C') AND
        STOCK_NUMBER IS NOT NULL
  ) M
JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,MATERIAL_NUMBER,GRID_VALUE,SAP_PO_NUMBER,
      QUANTITY,
      SUM(QUANTITY) OVER(PARTITION BY SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,MATERIAL_NUMBER,GRID_VALUE,SAP_PO_NUMBER) SUM_QUANTITY
    FROM VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW
    WHERE STOCK_TYPE IN ('L','B')
  ) A
ON M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER AND
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER AND
    M.STOCK_NUMBER = A.SAP_PO_NUMBER AND
    M.SIZE_LITERAL = A.GRID_VALUE AND
    M.MATERIAL = A.MATERIAL_NUMBER

WHERE M.SUM_QUANTITY <> A.SUM_QUANTITY

GROUP BY M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.MATERIAL, 
    M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
    M.SIZE_LITERAL,
    A.GRID_VALUE,
    M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    M.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    M.PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE,
    M.PLANT_CODE,
    M.STOCK_TYPE

ORDER BY
    M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.SIZE_LITERAL;
```

Comment: that still gives the similar result - I think there are more differences in the data sets than I thought.  I appreciate the feedback, subquery was my next go to.

Comment: @user3496218 - try to check one more variant. I added it at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so there were more differences in the data sets than I thought originally.  The below solution seems to work perfect (so far).  It is difficult as our DB's are managed globally and sometimes changes sneak in that end-users aren't made aware of. It's a beast of a query and takes like 5 minutes to run but it returns the right results so far - for reference we have 4 stock types (A,B,C,L) - the goal was to exclude A and C - I did it in an kind of round about way:

```
SELECT
    M.STOCK_NUMBER AS [PO_NUMBER],
    M.MATERIAL, 
    M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
    M.SIZE_LITERAL,
    A.GRID_VALUE,
    M1.QUANTITY [PO_QTY],
    SUM(A.QUANTITY) AS [SO_QTY],
    M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    M.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    M.PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE AS [ETA],
    M.PLANT_CODE,
    M.STOCK_TYPE

FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION M
JOIN VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW A   
    ON M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER AND
       M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER AND
       M.STOCK_NUMBER = A.SAP_PO_NUMBER AND
       M.SIZE_LITERAL = A.GRID_VALUE AND
       M.MATERIAL = A.MATERIAL_NUMBER
JOIN   (SELECT M1.STOCK_NUMBER,M1.MATERIAL,M1.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,M1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,M1.SIZE_LITERAL,SUM(M1.QUANTITY) AS [QUANTITY] FROM VW_MRP_ALLOCATION M1 
        GROUP BY M1.STOCK_NUMBER,M1.MATERIAL,M1.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,M1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,M1.SIZE_LITERAL,M1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER) AS [M1]
ON     M.STOCK_NUMBER = M1.STOCK_NUMBER AND
       M.MATERIAL = M1.MATERIAL AND 
       M1.MATERIAL = A.MATERIAL_NUMBER AND
       M1.SIZE_LITERAL = A.GRID_VALUE AND 
       M1.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER AND 
       M1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER = A.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER
JOIN   (SELECT A1.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,A1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,A1.MATERIAL_NUMBER,A1.GRID_VALUE,A1.SAP_PO_NUMBER,SUM(A1.QUANTITY) AS [QUANTITY] FROM VW_ARUN_NORM_NEW A1
        WHERE STOCK_TYPE IN ('L','B')
        GROUP BY A1.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER,A1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER,A1.MATERIAL_NUMBER,A1.GRID_VALUE,A1.SAP_PO_NUMBER) AS [A1]
ON     A1.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER = M1.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER AND 
       A1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER = M1.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER AND 
       A1.MATERIAL_NUMBER = M1.MATERIAL AND 
       A1.GRID_VALUE = M1.SIZE_LITERAL 

WHERE
    M.REQUIREMENT_TYPE = 'KE' AND
    M.STOCK_TYPE NOT IN ('A','C') AND
    M.STOCK_NUMBER IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY
    M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.MATERIAL, 
    M.MATERIAL_DESCRIPTION, 
    M.SIZE_LITERAL, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_NUMBER, 
    M.SALES_ORDER_ITEM_NUMBER, 
    M.CUSTOMER_NAME, 
    M.PLANNED_RECEIPT_DATE,
    M.PLANT_CODE, 
    A.GRID_VALUE,
    M.STOCK_TYPE,
    M1.QUANTITY,
    A1.QUANTITY

HAVING M1.QUANTITY <> A1.QUANTITY

ORDER BY
    M.STOCK_NUMBER,
    M.SIZE_LITERAL;
```

Comment: Did you not forget `AND M1.STOCK_NUMBER = A1.SAP_PO_NUMBER` in your query?

Comment: yep I did - long night!  Results are the same but better safe than sorry. Thanks!